# I don't know why my code won't run

Tags: java

I'm making a calculator program, and I got everything setup and it was working earlier, but after I added a method, when I run in debug mode, Eclipse says I have an error in my main method. I don't know why it won't run.

The error I get:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
at com.molotuff.main.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:13)
```

Here is my code:

```
package com.molotuff.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    private static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static boolean running = true;
    private static boolean calcRunning = true;
    private static String command;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        System.out.println("* Welcome to The Calculator *");
        System.out.println("*****************************");
        menu("help");

        while(running) {
            System.out.println("Enter a command:");
            command = reader.nextLine();
            menu(command);
            if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                running = false;
            }
            if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                getNums();
                int answer = Calculations.sum(nums);
                System.out.println("The sum is: " + answer);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void menu(String command) {
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
        System.out.println("Commands: ");
        System.out.println("Quit");
        System.out.println("Help");
        System.out.println("Add");
        System.out.println("Subtract");
        System.out.println("Divide");
        System.out.println("Multiply");
        System.out.println("Type help [command] for more info on that command");
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("help quit")) {
            System.out.println("Quit: quits the program.");
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("help help")) {
            System.out.println("Help: prints the help menu.");
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("help add")) {
            System.out.println("Add: takes numbers inputed and adds them together.");
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("help Subtract")) {
            System.out.println("Subtract: takes a set of numbers and subtracts     them \n (note: "
                    + "subtracts in this order [first num entered] - [second num entered] "
                    + "etc.)");
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("help multiply")) {
            System.out.println("Add: takes numbers inputed and multiplies them     together.");
        }
        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("help divide")) {
            System.out.println("Subtract: takes a set of numbers and divides     them \n (note: "
                    + "divides in this order [first num entered] / [second num     entered] " 
                    + "etc.)");
        }

    }
}

    public static void getNums() {
        while(calcRunning) {
            String userInput = reader.nextLine();
            int userNums;
            if(userInput.isEmpty()) {
                calcRunning = false;
            } else {
                userNums = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
                nums.add(userNums);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 'Eclipse says I have an error in my main method' - what error? Is this a compiler error? Runtime Error?

Comment: You've got an extra closing brace ('}') before your getNums method.

Comment: This is what it tells me  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at com.molotuff.main.Calculator.main(Calculator.java:13)

Comment: Method `static void getNums()` is out of the class scope. You need to remove extra } above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove a closing brackets `}` before `getNums()` method.You have closed the class after `menu()` this is why `getNums()` is not included in class body giving you the error.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I missed that since I thought I went through the brackets many times.. It's also strange that Eclipse didn't show that up as an error while I was coding.